# Unable to connect IIDR CDC to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, cdc, ibm-infosphere

When trying to connect IIDR replication engine for kafka to a kafka cluster via Zookeeper, I am getting the following error

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT","PLAINTEXT_HOST":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT:
//broker:29092","PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092"],"jmx_port":9101,"host":"broker","timestamp":"1598174513950","port":29092,"version":4}
at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:101)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getBrokerInfo(ZkUtils.scala:787)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokersInCluster$2.apply(ZkUtils.scala:162)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$$anonfun$getAllBrokersInCluster$2.apply(ZkUtils.scala:162)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at kafka.utils.ZkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster(ZkUtils.scala:162)
at com.datamirror.ts.target.publication.KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.getBootstrapBrokers(KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.java:829)
at com.datamirror.ts.target.publication.KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.loadKafkaServicesInfo(KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.java:417)
at com.datamirror.ts.target.publication.KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.handleStartReplicateMessage(KafkaTargetPublisherProxy.java:139)
at com.datamirror.ts.enginemsg.MessageDispatcher.dispatchSwitch(MessageDispatcher.java:547)
at com.datamirror.ts.enginemsg.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:142)
at com.datamirror.ts.engine.ReplicationSession.dispatchDynamicMessage(ReplicationSession.java:2816)
at com.datamirror.ts.engine.ReplicationSession.dispatchDataMessage(ReplicationSession.java:2910)
at com.datamirror.ts.target.publication.TargetDataChannelJob.moderateForTheTarget(TargetDataChannelJob.java:178)
at com.datamirror.ts.target.publication.TargetDataChannelJob.execute(TargetDataChannelJob.java:74)
at com.datamirror.ts.engine.component.PipelineThread.runThread(PipelineThread.java:217)
at com.datamirror.ts.util.TsThread.run(TsThread.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.PLAINTEXT_HOST
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:249)
at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.valueOf(SecurityProtocol.java:28)
at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol.forName(SecurityProtocol.java:89)
at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.createEndPoint(EndPoint.scala:49)
at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:90)
at kafka.cluster.Broker$$anonfun$1.apply(Broker.scala:89)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:277)
at kafka.cluster.Broker$.createBroker(Broker.scala:89)
```

It seems like there is a compatibility issue between IIDR and my kafka cluster. Appreciate any advice on how to overcome this.

```
System setup
- IIDR v11.4 kafka engine setup
- Quick start confluent kafka docker setup, https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one, cd cp-all-in-one
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation for both Kafka these days and the IDR product is to use bootstrap.servers and list the brokers in the kafkaproducer.properties and kafkaconsumer.properties files.   Contact L2 with regards to zookeeper config if there is a need to pursue, but we strongly recommend using the bootstrap.servers parameter as per Apache Kafka recommendations.